# compiler not detecting type using var keyword in visual studio

Tags: c#, var, type-inference

In the following code, `row` is considered as `object` and not `DataGridViewRow`.

```
foreach (var row in datagridview.Rows)
{
   row.Visible = false  //<- error because no Visible property
}
```

Am I missing something? shouldn't row be `DataGridViewRow`?

Comment: ``Rows`` is not inheriting from `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Try writing out the full type of row first as `foreach (WhateverRowShouldBe row in datagridview.Rows) { ... } ` That should get you a helpful error message.

Comment: Side note: proper title should be "I don't like type compiler detects for `var` in `foreach`" :) because compile uses `object` there as explained in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DataGridView.Rows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a collection which inherits from [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you will need to use [`OfType<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`Cast<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert it to `IEnumerable<T>` which are under **System.Linq** namespace, so you have to add `using System.Linq` in your code file:

```
foreach (var row in datagridview.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow)
{
   row.Visible = false  //<- error because no Visible property
}
```

or you can cast it in foreach to `DataGridViewRow`, if you dont want to use `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>()`:

```
foreach (DataGridView row in datagridview.Rows)
{
   row.Visible = false  //<- error because no Visible property
}
```

Comment: just as side note `Cast<T>()` and `OfType<T>()` are part of System.Linq namespace. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Your call to `datagridview.Rows` returns an instance of type [`DataGridViewRowCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), which implements the **non-generic** `ICollection`, `IEnumerable` and `IList` interfaces, thus, when you do "foreach" it will return instances of type `System.Object`.

When using an [implicitly typed variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) with the `var row` statement, the type of the `row` variable will now become `System.Object`.

To solve this, you can specify the type for `row` explicitly in the `foreach` statement:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview.Rows)
{
   row.Visible = false;
}
```

This works, because the `foreach` implementation silently performs an explicit conversion (cast) of each object returned from the `Enumerator.Current` to type  `DataGridViewRow`, as you can read about [here](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that compiler can not deduce type from datagridviewrowcollection

Comment: datagridview.Rows has no .List property are you sure the property correct?

Comment: @MusuNaji, you are right. it actually does have this property (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.list(v=vs.110).aspx) but it is a protected property. I will remove it from this answer

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop of course, Alex's answer is a good answer but I prefer Ehsan Sajjad's, it is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you all for your support.

Comment: @MusuNaji Ah, that answer came up after I commented. All good.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically set the type to DataGridViewRow.  Here's why:

`DataGridView.Rows` is of type `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection`.  If we refractor that class, we get this:

```
public class DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection : BaseCollection, IList
```

The type is never specified, there are no generics used, just Plain old collections.

Therefore, .net cannot automatically infer a type.  You have to specifically set the type to DataGridViewRow.

I'm guessing this is from the .Net days, when there were no generics.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
for(var i =0;i< datagridview.Rows.Count;i++)
{ var row = datagridview.Rows[i];
   row.Visible = false  
}
```

Comment: For the curious: The reason this works is because internally that class returns the type DataGridViewRow. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewRowCollection.cs,256

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewRowCollection implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`.

As such, it gives you a sequence of `object` not of `DataGridViewRow`.

Now the form:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in datagridview.Rows)
{
   row.Visible = false;
}
```

... will work, because `foreach` involves in inherent cast.

This was a great convenience in the days of .NET1.0 and 1.1 when there were no generics and as such not generic enumerators. Today it's less useful than it was (especially as it means some things that will not work at runtime will still compile, that could be caught without this inherent cast), but it will work for you here.

`var` though will always be of the type of the expression, which in this case is `object`.